# Screen Display Options Missing - Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, display, monitor

New to Ubuntu. I have downloaded the latest version and installed it on an HP laptop. Attached is a screenshot of the display options. The laptop is connected to a monitor via a docking station.
It charges and recognizes the keyboard and the mouse.

However, it does not recognize the external displays.

[image: Screenshot]

**System Details:**
Laptop Model:1040 X360 Elitebook G2
Docking Station: HP G2
Monitor: HP EliteDisplay E190i

Is this something that can be fixed? Or would Ubuntu provide an update?

The Screenshot attached does not show any options for monitors.
I've also changed privacy settings to automatically detect a dock.

Comment: What does the "Screen Display" tab show?

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thank you for your response.
The Display Tab only shows
'Buit-in display'
Orientation
Resolution
Refresh Rate
Scale
Fractional Scaling
The top two tabs are ' Screen Display' and 'Night Light'

Comment: Hi All,
I've followed instructions on this website:
https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
and it now works!!!
It was a DisplayLink driver I needed